# Set timeout to python socket connection recv method

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, http, networking

I am trying to write a simple http server. I want it to be functional for `Connection: keep-alive` header, so I want to make sure that `connection.recv()` will have a timeout. I've tried `socket.settimeout(timeout)` method but it closes the connection after `timeout` amount of time even if the data is recieved. What I want is something like:

```
while True:
    try:
        #start to wait for timeout seconds
        request = conn.recv(256, timeout)
        process()
        #if there is no keep-alive header end the operation
        if "keep-alive" not in request:
            conn.close()
            break
        else:
            #if there was a keep alive header start getting the data
            continue
    except:
        #this means timeout seconds passed after recv() was called
        conn.close()
        break
```

What's the best way of doing it?

Comment: I'd suggest not using bare exception handling like that, use something more specific.  also you want timeouts for other reasons, e.g. a malicious client that sends a byte every 10 seconds could hold a connection open for a **very** long time

Comment: My goal for now is not to make a http server ready for production, I am trying to learn. I want to learn exactly what I wrote, but thanks for comment anyway.

Comment: *"I've tried socket.settimeout(timeout) method but it closes the connection after timeout amount of time even if the data is recieved."* - according to documentation and code `socket.settimeout` sets the timeout for each socket operation (connect, read, ...) and does not just starts once a timer which triggers after timeout. If you experience different things please provide the code to show this, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details. Apart from set, you can use `socket.settimeout(None)` to remove any timeout.